# received string is not same when i use socket.recev in python it work fine in linux but not in windows ... Why?

Tags: java, python

I am having following problem with my client and server code like ,server is not able to receive if the new line character is not appended to the string that i am sending from the client.

"message is "DONE" statement receiving false " when server send the string "DONE"

Client code : [Python ]

```
 connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connection.connect((server_address, server_port))
   # unicodeconv = unicode(methodname, "utf-8")
   # time.sleep(50)
    connection.send(methodname)
    message = connection.recv(1024)
   # print(unicode(message, "utf-8"))
    print message
    print (unichr(message))
    print (message is "DONE")
```

Server Code : [ JAVA]

```
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4099);  
System.out.println("wait for connection");
while(true)
{
Socket s=ss.accept();  
BufferedReader din = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter dout = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
String str="",str2="DONE";  
str=din.readLine(); 
dout.println(str2); 
System.out.println(" Client - "+str);
```

Comment: You could try something like `if(!string.endsWith("/n")) {string+="/n"}` in java to detect if a newline is present, and append it, if not.

Comment: I refer the example in the below link .. it's working fine in linux .. but string comparison fails in windows                [/how-to-connect-a-python-client-to-java-server-with-tcp-sockets/](https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/how-to-connect-a-python-client-to-java-server-with-tcp-sockets/)

Comment: String comparison you say? You wouldn't happen to be using `==` with `String`s, would you? We must compare `String`s with `String.equals(String str)`. For example we mustn't `if(string1 == string2)`, but `if(string1.equals(string2))` instead.

Comment: "string1.equals(string2)" method is not available in python ... As i mentioned when i received the string from the java server .. it just fails `sock.sendall("Hello\n")
data = sock.recv(1024)
print "1)", data
 
if ( data == "olleH\n" ):
    print("yes")`

Comment: My advice is for java, I haven't enough experience with pythons bindings of `Socket`.